# Presto configuration

Tags: presto, trino

As I set up a cluster of Presto and try to do some performance tuning, I wonder if there's a more comprehensive configuration guide of Presto, e.g. how can I control how many CPU cores a Presto worker can use. And is it good practice if I start multiple presto workers on a single server (in which case I don't need a dedicated server to run the coordinator)?

Besides, I don't quite understand the task.max-memory argument. Will the presto worker start multiple tasks for a single query? If yes, maybe I can use task.max-memory together with the -Xmx JVM argument to control the level of parallelism?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

Presto is a multithreaded Java program and works hard to use all available CPU resources when processing a query (assuming the input table is large enough to warrant such parallelism). You can artificially constrain the amount of CPU resources that Presto uses at the operating system level using cgroups, CPU affinity, etc.

There is no reason or benefit to starting multiple Presto workers on a single machine. You should not do this because they will needlessly compete with each other for resources and likely perform worse than a single process would.

We use a dedicated coordinator in our deployments that have 50+ machines because we found that having the coordinator process queries would slow it down while it performs the query coordination work, which has a negative impact on overall query performance. For small clusters, dedicating a machine to coordination is likely a waste of resources. You'll need to run some experiments with your own cluster setup and workload to determine which way is best for your environment.

You can have a single Presto process act as both a coordinator and worker, which can be useful for tiny clusters or testing purposes. To do so, add this to the `etc/config.properties` file:

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
```

Your idea of starting a dedicated coordinator process on a machine shared with a worker process is interesting. For example, on a machine with 16 processors, you could use cgroups or CPU affinity to dedicate 2 cores to the coordinator process and restrict the worker process to 14 cores. We have never tried this, but it could be a good option for small clusters.

A task is a stage in a query plan that runs on a worker (the CLI shows the list of stages while the query is running). For a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t`, there will be a task on every work that performs the table scan and partial aggregation, and another task on a single worker for the final aggregation. More complex queries that have joins, subqueries, etc., can result in multiple tasks on every worker node for a single query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, very informative. In fact I want to use multiple workers because of this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5276. We first ran into this problem with spark, which also adopts the multiple-thread model. Anyway I think it'd be better to make the available number of cores configurable. As for the task, how many tasks does the worker start to process a query? If I don't have to run multiple queries simultaneously, can I set task.max-memory the same as Xmx?

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that issue. We haven't seen that in our tests, but we normally use the Facebook version of Hadoop which might have fixed this. If this turns out to be a problem for Presto, we'll work around it on our end rather than forcing every end user to do hacks like running multiple workers on a single machine. Our philosophy for Presto is that everything should "just work" as much as possible so that you don't have to worry about these sorts of details when running Presto.

Comment: The name "task" in Presto is used differently than in systems like Hadoop. For example, when running `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t`, then coordinator will first create tasks on the workers for the table scan stage, then it will assign "splits" to the task for execution. The task is the "container" for the work. Thus, there is only ever a single task on a worker per stage in a query. The number of threads used for running splits concurrently is controlled by `task.shard.max-threads`, but you shouldn't have to change it.

Comment: Presto doesn't currently have any limits on the number of concurrent queries. We sometimes see dozens or hundreds of concurrent queries in production with no issues. Controlling the number of processors used for a Java program is best left to the operating system, given that the OS is responsible for all thread scheduling. There is no feasible way to do that from within the JVM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for being helpful :)

Comment: hi, when I run some query with Presto, I found this exception in the coordinator's log: ContinuousTaskInfoFetcher-20131121_021432_00008_jyezc.2.1-3017  com.facebook.presto.server.HttpRemoteTask   Error updating task 20131121_021432_00008_jyezc.2.1: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection to /192.168.150.108:3264 timed out. Any suggestions what may be wrong or how I can increase the connection time out?

Comment: Stack Overflow comments aren't appropriate for this. Please ask this on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/presto-users

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx must be higher than task.max-memory, or at least equal.
otherwise you will be likely to see OOM issue as I have experienced that before.
and also, since Presto-0.113 they have changed the way Presto manages the query memory and according configurations.
please refer to this link:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

For your question regarding "many CPU cores a Presto worker can use", I think it's controlled by the parameter `task.concurrency`, which by default is 16